# Maximization Problem

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, mathematical-optimization, maximum

I am trying to find the solution of the following problem.

$ \max_{n_{\in [1,M]}} \frac{n \left(\frac{k (n-2 (\rho -1) \tau )}{\frac{k n (n-2 (\rho -1) \tau )}{2 (n+1)^2}+1}-2 \rho  (\tau -1)\right)}{2 (n+1)^2} $

sub. to $M\geq2$, $k>1$ and $\rho,\tau \in (0,1)$.

To do this in Mathematica, I try to follow two routes.

First, I use Maximize, and I write the following:

```
Maximize[{(n (-2 \[Rho] (-1 + \[Tau]) + (k (n - 2 (-1 + \[Rho]) \[Tau]))/(1 + (k n (n - 2 (-1 + \[Rho]) \[Tau]))/(2 (1 + n)^2))))/(2 (1 + n)^2), 1 <= n <= M && 0 < \[Tau] < 1 && 0 < \[Rho] < 1 && k > 1 && M >= 2},n]
```

This does not work: at some point, I abort the evaluation (I let it work all night).

Second, I know that the maximand function is concave. And I compute the FOC's and SOC's.

```
fmax=(n (-2 \[Rho] (-1 + \[Tau]) + (k (n - 2 (-1 + \[Rho]) \[Tau]))/(1 + (k n (n - 2 (-1 + \[Rho]) \[Tau]))/(2 (1 + n)^2))))/(2 (1 + n)^2)
Solve[{D[fmax, n] == 0, D[D[fmax, n], n] < 0 && 0 < \[Tau] < 1 && 0 < \[Rho] < 1 && k > 1},n]
```

I obtain a Root expression from this code, which I cannot evaluate qualitatively.

From

```
Manipulate[Plot[(n (-2 \[Rho] (-1 + \[Tau]) + (k (n - 2 (-1 + \[Rho]) \[Tau]))/(1 + (k n (n - 2 (-1 + \[Rho]) \[Tau]))/(2 (1 + n)^2))))/(2 (1 + n)^2), {n, 1, 500}], {\[Tau], 0, 1}, {\[Rho], 0, 1}, {k, 0, 10}]
```

I can check that the function is concave and for some values of the parameters it has an interior maximizer.

My goal here is to find the maximizer and characterize it in terms of the other parameters.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your function `f[n,k,\[Rho,\[Tau]]`,seems to be positive and monoton growing with `n ,k`! I would expect maximum `Limit[f[n,k,\[Rho,\[Tau]],n->Infinity]=k/(2 + k)`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Thanks a lot for your comment. You can check graphically that the function is not always monotone increasing. In some cases, it has an interior maximizer. For instance, you could check that `NMaximize[Limit[(n (-2 \[Rho] (-1 + \[Tau]) + (k (n - 2 (-1 + \[Rho]) \[Tau]))/(1 + (k n (n - 2 (-1 + \[Rho]) \[Tau]))/(2 (1 + n)^2))))/(2 (1 + n)^2), {k -> 6, \[Rho] -> 1/2, \[Tau] -> 1/3}], n]`  yields an interior solution.

Comment: Your `NMaximize` gives `{0.75018, {n -> 56.9418}}` .For `n=54` or `n=57` functionvalue gives `0.75018` too

Comment: `Manipulate[
 Plot[Table[(n (-2 \[Rho] (-1 + \[Tau]) + (k (n - 
             2 (-1 + \[Rho]) \[Tau]))/(1 + (k n (n - 
                2 (-1 + \[Rho]) \[Tau]))/(2 (1 + n)^2))))/(2 (1 + 
         n)^2), {k, 1, 10}], {n, 1, 50}], {{\[Tau], 1/3}, 0, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{\[Rho], 1/2}, 0, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"} ]` perhaps confirms my guess about monotonie

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Sorry, I don't get your point. If you plot the function as I suggested in the question, do you also get that the function can have an interior maximizer in  `n` ? This happens with `\[Tau]` "low" and `\[Rho]` "intermediate". Don't you get the same? Thanks again for helping

Comment: My point is: Functionvalue takes the same value nearby the maximum, functionvalue is constant and maximum isn't unique!

Comment: Is it at all useful that the maximum function value is rather near k/(k+2)?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Got it now. Thanks a lot! I was wondering whether Mathematica has a more convenient way to maximize functions expect for the command that I tried. I am new to thelanguage

Comment: @Alan I see it now. Maybe yes, even if I was looking for an expression for the maximizer as a function of parameters.